# Email highcharts pdf

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts

I managed to export multiple charts as pdf and download it on client side. Is there a way to email that pdf to email that user types. I was not able to find anything. I am using .net framework on server side.

Is it possible to send pdf to server using ajax and to send it to email from server that way?

Comment: Check this : https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2016/02/11/c-server-side-rendering-with-highcharts/ . he is saving svg to server, try to do if pdf possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've got the PDF content and the email address to send it to from the client side, you can send email via .NET from your back-end server. This used to be done via the built-in `SmtpClient` class but Microsoft now recommends people to use other options like [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead.

You're also going to need an email server to connect to which will handle the delivery of those emails. This could be Gmail if you already have an account or an alternative like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/)

As far as getting the PDF content of the chart, Highcharts appears to be taking the SVG content of the chart and using [svg2pdf](https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js/) to produce the PDF when not using an export server.

Since there appears to be no (documented) way of exporting to anything other than a file, you're likely going to need to mimic this process yourself by taking the SVG content via [chart.getSVG()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#getSVG) and then using `svg2pdf` to get your PDF content to send to your server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know I can send it from server side, but I don't know how to send this pdf to server from client. I am using highcharts export and I am not sure I can even do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some notes on getting the PDF.

Comment: I've tried to do that. I think I generated corret SVG but I will update this if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is a client html2print generator and like jsPDF or other client based solutions the PDF generation is per user selection of PDF printout options. (The client has control over PDF so no need for them to email it to self or others, unless they have to.)

Per [link](https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2016/02/11/c-server-side-rendering-with-highcharts/) above

> However, for situations where you may be generating a report for a client who has just seen the screen (and you don't need to change the chart in anyway) - why would you want to render the chart server side? when the client has already done the work.

[image]

To build server side automatically using a browser the server needs generally to process it, just like a user, with say `chrome --headless options for html2pdf` (and chrome can normally do that in one line, but with limited user layout options).
At that point you could have a PDF for attachment by any conventional mime application/pdf means (e.g. convert to base64.txt).

***However*** due to the more dynamic drawing of svg (rather than a static insert) I could not run an Out.PDF --headless just by CLI, so it would need a driven solution such as selenium/puppeteer. THUS you may need to follow the suggestions in the lee-m above answer to build and modify the svg output.

for me I was able to run printEdge.vbs (with my current landscape defaults)

```
DIM shell
SET shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "cmd /c start msedge.exe file:///C:/Users/WDAGUtilityAccount/Documents/highchart.htm"
WScript.Sleep(4000)
Shell.SendKeys "^p"
WScript.Sleep(3000)
Shell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
Shell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
Shell.SendKeys "y"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
Shell.SendKeys "{esc}"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
Shell.SendKeys "%{f4}"
```